# Question about symbol detection in ISI channels (use of APP decoder in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, channelcoding

I am studying the problem of digital symbols detection in ISI channel. In the figure below, the output symbol is represented as a weighted sum of input symbols.

[image]

I am trying to use MAP decoder `comm.APPDecoder` to estimate the transmit symbols. To construct the trellis of such figure, I am using the Matlab function `poly2trellis`. The function can be used as follows:

```
trellis = poly2trellis(ConstraintLength,CodeGenerator)
```

My question is how can I enter (or consider) the real-valued coefficients $\Gamma_{-L_2}, ..., \Gamma_{L_1}$ in the second input argument `CodeGenerator`. If these coefficients are binary, then it is straightforward to convert this binary sequence to octal. But, I have no clue with real-valued coefficients. Any hints?

Comment: `poly2trellis` is used for convolutional encoders which are defined by generators over binary fields. What you have in your figure, with real-valued coefficients, resembles more to a digital [`filter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) (more specifically an FIR filter which would have the feedback coefficients `a = 1`).

Comment: All your edits point to @SlothEye's initial suspicion being true - what you describe is a FIR filter, and the inverse of that isn't APPDecoder, but an equalizer.

Comment: Traditional equalization performance is not satisfactory if the ISI is sever. That is why I am looking for the optimal detection using APP decoder.

Comment: But what you describe is not a decoder problem. You first encode, then you apply a constellation and a pulse shape, then the isi channel happens, you then equalize, matched filter, de-constellation-map and then you decode. You get two problems: estimating the channel for the equalizer, and estimating the info bit sequence based on the code bit sequence. Isi doesn't happen to bits - it happens to symbols in their baseband shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, applying linear equalization (e.g. filtering with the inverse of the channel) will not yield the optimal performance. Though, what you are searching is not the `comm.APPDecoder` (which is solely for convolutional codes, i.e. bits with binary $\Gamma$), but you are looking for [maximum likelihood sequence estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_sequence_estimation) (MLSE).

Here, MATLAB offers the [`comm.MLSEEqualizer`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.mlseequalizer-class.html) object, which you can e.g. use like this:

```
Constellation = [1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j];
Channel = [1 0.7, 0.3, 0.2]';
sigma2 = 0.3;

tx = Constellation(randi(4, [100,1])).';

noise = sqrt(sigma2/2)*complex(randn(size(tx)), randn(size(tx)));
rx = filter(Channel, 1, tx) + noise;

mlse = comm.MLSEEqualizer('Channel',Channel,'Constellation',Constellation);

estimated = step(mlse, rx);

[estimated tx abs(estimated-tx)]
```

program output (only a few rows of it):

```
   1.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 - 1.0000i        0          
  -1.0000 + 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 1.0000i        0          
   1.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i        0          
   1.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i        0          
   1.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i        0          
  -1.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 - 1.0000i        0          
  -1.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 - 1.0000i        0          
   1.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i        0
```

as you see, the MLSE equalizer completely recovers the transmitted sequence.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. However, it is not exactly what I am looking for as it does not provide soft outputs (to use with outer channel decoder). If 'comm.APPDecoder' works only with binary $\Gamma$, then the only way is to write my own BCJR or MPA algorithms? Right?

Comment: Requiring soft-outputs requires a significant higher complexity and it is not natively available in Matlab. Yes, I think you would need to write this piece on your own, using the BCJR or similar approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I assume this function considers noise samples are white. If not while, then I need to change the effective channel input. I guess it will be convolution between original channel and whitening filter coefficients, right?

Comment: Well, I believe it assumes white noise. But, since it does not produce soft-output, it also has no parameter for the noise variance. In the documentation I could not find information about the assumed noise model. Right, if the noise were correlated, you'd need to send the signal through a whitening filter before (which is most likely an IIR filter), which increases the effective channel length and might even reduce performance. You would need to try this out. It's a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Do you recommend some good resources on these DSP and coding theory concepts?

Comment: In principle, this is estimation/detection theory. So, standard books are these from S.M. Kay for example. For your specific problem, you may have a look at http://portal.research.lu.se/portal/files/5784220/1738024.pdf , https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fd6e/531be56f3e420c4ec553e415bda380b48fae.pdf and references therein.